# Code will not print average for array of doubles

Tags: java, arrays, printing, average

Trying to write a method that calculates the average of values in an array of doubles but I cannot get the average value to print.  It compiles and executes but returns no results.

```
public class Test3Q1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    public static double average (double[]x) {
        double [] doubleValues = {3.0, 10.5, 19.8, 5.6, 3.2};
        double total = 0.0;
        for (int i =0; i<doubleValues.length; i++) {
        total += doubleValues[i];
        return total; }
        double average = total/doubleValues.length;


        System.out.println("The average of the doubles Array 
                               is: " + average);
        System.out.format("The average of the double array is: 
                             %.1f", average);
        return average;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning inside the loop?

Comment: You are also passing `double[] x` but not using it in the method.

Comment: And your `main` method never calls `average` either.

Comment: You have a return inside for sentence. You are not iterating over array and the println is not execute.

Answer (score 1):

This feels like a homework question to me, but I think something like this should solve your issues.

```
public class Test3Q1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double [] doubleValues = {3.0, 10.5, 19.8, 5.6, 3.2};

        double avg = average(doubleValues);

        System.out.println("The average of the doubles Array is: " + avg);
        System.out.format("The average of the double array is: %.1f", avg);
    }

    public static double average (double[] values) {
        double total = 0.0;

        for (int i =0; i<values.length; i++) {
            total += values[i];
        }

        return total/values.length;
    }
}
```

Note how you should not `return` inside the for loop in this case. <s>I also removed your `double[] x` from the `average` method parameters, as it was not needed in this case.</s> I have edited the answer to include the parameter `double[] values` again, as it makes the method more versatile, since you can now plug any array of `double`s in.

Comment: Why not leave the `double[] x` as a parameter and move the `doubleValues ` array to main, so that the method is reusable to calculate other averages for some other input?

Comment: @Eritrean I had thought about doing that, but I wasn't sure what his requirements were. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning total from within the for loop. That's why it's not printing anything.
Comment the return total statement from the for loop and it prints the average correctly.

Comment: Afraid return in the loop is not the only issue. See comments above.

Answer (score 0):

```
return total; // delete that
```

It's escaping you out of your method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i see there is nothing in main code, that's why it compiles but show no results. You must call the method in `main` but erasing the parameter `double[]x` cause you aren't using it.